# Can I replace the word of "whose" with "which"?

Tags: grammar

Sentence：Don’t use a word the meaning **whose** you don’t understand.

Q：
Can I replace the word of "**whose**" with "**which**" ?

Analyse as below：
[image]

Comment: *Whose* should not be used in that construction in the first place—nor does the image you provided show it being used. It's not a question of *can* you replace it.

Comment: Essentially, you have two options: "Don’t use a word whose meaning you don’t understand" and "Don’t use a word the meaning of which you don’t understand".

Comment: Hi, track890, and welcome to ELL. It's generally best to transcribe images, rather than just including and image that contains text. The search system can't index the text in images, and people who use screen reader software can't get it to read that text to them either.

Answer (score 2):

Neither "the meaning which you don't understand" nor "the meaning whose you don't understand", is grammatical.

The grammatical forms are

> *the meaning of which you don't understand* (more literary)
>
> *whose meaning you don't understand*
>
> *that you don't understand the meaning of* (more colloquial)

Comment: Correction: _the meaning which you don't understand_ is grammatical, but not in that sentence, because it is a noun phrase containing a relative clause, not a relative clause itself.